# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} (\frac{x-1}{x+1})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

I'm studying the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \cdot (\frac{x-1}{x+1})^n$$

I have already shown that there is pointwise convergence for $x\in[0, +\infty)$ and total convergence in any interval $[0,a]$ with $a>0$, and there is not total convergence in the interval $[0,\infty)$.

> How can I prove or disprove the uniform convergence in the interval $[0,\infty)$?

For example: I know that if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly in $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$ in $A$. (This proposition is used to *disprove* the uniform convergence in a set). But in my case, this test is passed, since $$\text{sup}_{x\in [0,\infty)} |f_n(x)|=1/n$$ whch tends to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

> In general, are there any other useful tests like the one above to disprove the uniform convergence?
>   Are there sufficient conditions for uniform convergence (other than "total convergence implies uniform convergence")? Which are the the most useful tools (propositions, theorems, etc.) in studying the convergence of a series of functions?

Comment: what is total convergence?

Comment: @zhw, I have heard how some people (with Italian background) referred to uniform convergence as a "total convergence" and think that OP is among them.

Comment: @zhw. By total convergence I mean normal convergence. (In Italy we call it in this way) :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series fails to converge uniformly for $x \in [1,\infty)$, since for $x > 1$

$$\sup_{x \in [1,\infty)} \left|\sum_{n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)^k\right| \geqslant \sup_{x \in [1,\infty)} \sum_{n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)^k \geqslant \sup_{x \in [1,\infty)}n \cdot\frac{1}{2n}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)^{2n} \\ \geqslant \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{4n-1-1}{4n -1 +1} \right)^{2n} = \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2n},$$

and the RHS converges to $e^{-1}/2 \neq 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Failure to converge uniformly on $[1,\infty)$ implies that convergence in non-uniform on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Wonderful and very elegant! Can you give some hints on how did you come up with this calculations? It seems so magical...I could never have thought of such a thing

Comment: @Minato:  Once you establish that the series converges pointwise, i.e., the sequence of partial sums $S_n(x)$ converges to $S(x)$, then uniform convergence for $x \in D$  means for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ independent of $x$ such that $|S_n(x) - S(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$ and all $x \in D$.  This is true if and only if $\sup_{x \in D} |S_n(x) - S(x)| \to 0$.  The sequence of remainders $|S_n(x) - S(x)|$ is $\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty a_k(x)\right|$ and I showed in this case it can't converge to $0$ with a lower bounding sequence that fails to converge to $0$.

Comment: Bounding below by a sum with finitely many terms, $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} a_k(x)$ is a common trick.  It is also equivalent to showing that a uniform Cauchy criterion is not satisfied.

Comment: There are many examples like this on Math.SE, for example [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2377254/148510) here.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following approach is pretty universal to prove that something doesn't converge uniformly on some unbounded interval.

Suppose that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n$ converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$. Then $\forall\varepsilon>0$ $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall x>0$ and $\forall k,m\geq N$
$$|\sum\limits_{n=k}^m\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n|<\varepsilon.$$
Note that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n=\frac{1}{n}$ and since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ diverges we have $\sum\limits_{n=k}^m\frac{1}{n}\geq\varepsilon$. That means $\exists x_0\in[0,\infty)$ such that
$$|\sum\limits_{n=k}^m\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x_0-1}{x_0+1}\right)^n|\geq\varepsilon,$$
that is a contradiction. So, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n$ doesn't converge uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you. Please let me rephrase your answer to see if I understood it well. Suppose the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n$ converges uniformly in $[0,\infty)$. Let $\varepsilon>0$, then there exists $\nu \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m\ \ge k \ge \nu$ we have $$\left|\sum\limits_{n=k}^m\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n\right| <\varepsilon/2 \text{ for all $x$ in $[0,\infty)$}$$

Comment: Taking the sup for $x\in [0,\infty)$ we have $$\left|\sum\limits_{n=k}^m\frac{1}{n}\right| \le\varepsilon/2<\varepsilon $$ So we have shown that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is $\nu \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $m \ge k \ge \nu$ we have $$\left|\sum\limits_{n=k}^m\frac{1}{n}\right| <\varepsilon$$, i.e. that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ converges, which is absurd! Am I right?

Comment: @Minato, yes, you're right. I also corrected a typo with quantifiers order in my answer.